# Mysql: same query, same number of resulting rows, no joins, 10x slower?

Tags: mysql, database-performance

I'm running the following two queries on a innodb table that contains ~3M rows. For some reason the first query takes less than a second to return 168,199 rows whereas the second query takes 8 seconds and returns 167,159 rows? The time it takes to return almost the same results increases by a factor of 10?

```
SELECT count(idActivities) as amt 
FROM Activities 
WHERE Data_Type='email' 
      AND Status='sent' 
      AND (Created > '2019-07-17 00:00:00' 
           AND Created <= '2019-08-17 00:00:00');

SELECT count(idActivities) as amt 
FROM Activities 
WHERE Data_Type='email' 
      AND Status='sent' 
      AND (Created > '2019-08-17 00:00:00' 
           AND Created <= '2019-09-17 00:00:00');
```

If I remove the additional where clauses from the second statement e.g.

```
SELECT count(idActivities) as amt 
FROM Activities 
WHERE (Created > '2019-08-17 00:00:00' 
       AND Created <= '2019-09-17 00:00:00');
```

The query time drops to half a second. If I add a single additional where clause to the statement e.g. Data_Type= or Status= it jumps back to 8 plus seconds.

I've also tried moving the dates a few days in either direction but this doesn't affect the query time.

The table is indexed on idActivities, Data_Type, Status and Created.

The server is running 5GB Ram, 8 cores and has innodb_buffer_pool_size=3G, InnoDB buffer usage is at 49%.

I've tried the same query on a different server and the results are roughly the same time around ~4 seconds which is still pretty slow.

The only difference I've noticed is that the cardinality of the Data_Type column is different even though the table is virtually the same (it's a back up from the day before).

I would appreciate any help or assistance in understanding how to improve the query time? Running "DISTINCT(Data_Type)" only returns 13 rows for the entire table.

**EDITED** 
Thank you Salman A, by adding the following composite index massively improved the performance of both queries:

CREATE INDEX ix_1 ON Activities (Created, Data_Type, Status);

Comment: '*I'm running the following two queries on a innodb table that contains ~3M rows.*' - You should really consider backing up and removing some rows if all are not needed.

Comment: Do you have any multi-column indexes?

Comment: You might see improved results time because of caching. Try and modify the high performance queries by changing a character from upper case to lower case (`SeLECT` for example) and see if the query has the same speed.

Comment: @Script47 - indeed. The challenge is that the table increases by approximately 170,000 rows per month and there are other queries that go back multiple months.

Comment: @Salman A - No multi column indexes. Here is a link to an image of the index: https://gx6cmw.sn.files.1drv.com/y4mUoriI3Qv0deVL_-tG4luJezwNUZLQYyoLxiVQZs-q96OZJqNVkASPeZBBpMEhs3DKMlYUST2gvk_nKP7KjVgc1tpRDWDod6MCiObJoO1gfuv51JtaJ9uIdalKSSsA93Vn1tawkF9hgfkYwdYbTH8PR8O2rPsGvV_XF7WQKvfrq-r7sP0ThQ20-c9LmnyiNGFhvf7x5K5GC0_F-ySbVl9dw?width=707&height=104&cropmode=none - Can't post images yet :S

Comment: @Tudor Constantin - changed case on a couple of different elements such as data_type from Data_Type and no real difference in the query times.

Comment: That's a weird behavior indeed. I think @Salman A's answer might be a good solution.

Comment: If your indexes are only on individual columns, the query will hit one index, and then table scan that result set for the other items in the where clause. Which index gets hit is up to the DB (unless you give it a hint), if you check the query plans, you'll probably find different primary indexes are hit for the different queries. @Salman A has the correct solution - create a compound index that references all the columns, in the same order as the query.

Comment: Use `COUNT(*)` instead of `count(idActivities)` (unless you need to check `idActivities` for `NULL`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest creating the following covering index:

```
 CREATE INDEX ix_1 ON t (Data_Type, Status, Created)
```

The order of columns matter. High cardinality columns are usually placed first, but for this particular query you need to put the created column at the end since it involves range comparison (the first two require equality comparison).

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try adding the covering index and see if that helps.

Comment: Genius! Both queries are down to less than half a second! Thank you! :)

Comment: @olly be advised that I've revised the answer.

Comment: @SalmanA - (Replacing my comment) - Cardinality does not control the preferred ordering.  Instead, put `=` columns first (in _any_ order), then the range test.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a Composite Index here with a specific order of columns in it. The general rule of thumb is:

1. First priority should be given to all the columns, which are inside the `WHERE` clause, and are connected by `AND` clause, and are **compared to a constant value** using either `=`, `IS NULL`, or `<=>`. So, in your query, there are two columns following this: `Data_Type` and `Status`.
2. Second priority can be given to following three scenarios:

   - Column having Range condition.
   - Columns in a specific order in the `GROUP BY` clause (if existing).
   - Columns in a specific order in the `ORDER BY` clause (if existing)

In this case, `Created` is a Range condition, so we will add that column to the index at the end, because on encountering range condition, MySQL stops at the column, and does not access further columns in the index.

So, you basically need to define the following index:

```
ALTER TABLE Activities ADD INDEX(Data_Type, Status, Created);
```

Quoting from [Rick James' notes](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#flags_and_low_cardinality):

> When you have a composite index that could be in any order, the
>   cardinality of the individual columns does not matter in picking the
>   order. The cardinality of the entire index is what matters.

Comment: @SalmanA please read: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#algorithm_end Also read about BTREE+ structure

Comment: @SalmanA here's one more: https://ibb.co/HpW9PHm This screenshot is from [High Performance MySQL](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/high-performance-mysql/9781449332471/) book (authored by people behind Percona server). Now, best way to benchmark is to get the OP to run `EXPLAIN format=json` on both the queries and compare the costs and see it for ourselves.. But nevermind, most of the ppl are ignorant, so let it be...

Comment: Thanks for your input Madhur, appreciated, read and understood!

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya - (In that link...)  The `IN (<everything>)` fails to be useful in some situations, and may even slow down the query.

Comment: @RickJames thanks for letting know. Have you jotted down those cases on your blog yet ? Or some other link ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya - My understanding of `IN` is still too vague to add more than I already have in that blog.  It is sometimes as efficient as `=`, but sometimes approaches being as bad as a 'range'.  But I don't have reliable examples of which happens when.  And there have been a number of improvements, perhaps in this area, in 5.6, 5.7, and 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

When you have unexpected behavior like this I always check what the server is doing by getting it to explain what it's doing.

You can do this using the EXPLAIN keyword at the start of the query. I would guess that the slower query is scanning the entire table for your result set

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html

an aside note: unless your data_type and status columns are very selective (at a guess they would not be). I would take a guess that they are pointless indexes. Typically indexing status columns is only a good idea when you have a large proportion of one status type. i.e 95% closed 'status' and 5% 'open' and you have a query where you want to find all open statuses.

Comment: The amount of rows in explain is significantly greater in the slower query (1676411 vs 282116). What's interesting is the amount of actual rows in the queries if you remove the data_type and status, so just returning the date period is almost identical at ~194,000. Why is the slower query analyzing significantly more rows?

Comment: The optimizer is taking an educated guess at how many rows are going to be selected. It's guessing that in this case scanning three indexes is more expensive than scanning the table. You can either use index hints to try and force MySQL to use an index that you know is the most selective, or if you know this type of access pattern will be similar create an composite index based on date, status, data_type.

Comment: @Olly - The statistics used for `EXPLAIN` are often quite crude.  See [_Handler counts_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts) for much better counts.

Comment: Even if the flags are not very selective, there is a boost in converting the index to being "covering".

Comment: @el_oso -  MySQL almost never uses more than one index for one `SELECT`.  And when it does, it is often an indication that a composite index would be better.